# YouTubeAdnroidApi does not work in other emulator

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Currently i am working with *YoutubeAndroidApi* in Android. here this Application only run in  Nexus 4 hardware. so how can i run same application in other hardware?

Comment: Please could you attach some code snippet, or more information of your problem, because it is not enough for the community to help you.

Comment: I have create My Youtube Application in Android using YoutubeAndroidApi. This Application Run only  Nexus 4 hardware not to other hardware like Galaxy Nexus or etc. so how can i run my application in different different hardware?

Comment: I am not an experienced Youtube api developer, but as I know, you have to use the Android 4.4 and Youtube 4.2.16 or later. And check your registered key. I hope it helps. [Check the offical instruction for more help!](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup)

Comment: I have also Register key. And thats why i access that player in Nexus 4 hardware. But does not support other hardware. and no problem if any have knowledge than please post his answer.